# Informal relations

Tags: riddle, word

> Both my prefix prefix,
>   and my suffix suffix,
>   became so the same sec,
>   as my infix infix.

What am I?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am going to guess the answer is

> Panama

Both my prefix prefix

> Papa (informal for father)

and my suffix suffix,

> Mama (informal for mother)

became so the same sec,

> When their child was born

as my infix infix.

> Nana (informal for grandmother)

Comment: I hoped for a hat and this fits perfectly!

Comment: Haha, it suits you!